# Make threads start in particular order in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I would like to make a simple thread program that starts 3 threads in  order 1,2,3 and after that stops in order 3,2,1 just by using the sleep() method. However, everytime the threads start in different order.

```
class Thread1 extends Thread{   
  public void run(){        
     System.out.println("Thread 1 running...");
     try {
        this.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     System.out.println("Thread 1 has terminated");
  }
} 

class Thread2 extends Thread {
  public void run(){
     System.out.println("Thread 2 running...");
     try {
        this.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     System.out.println("Thread 2 has terminated");
  }
}

class Thread3 extends Thread {
  public void run(){
     System.out.println("Thread 3 running...");
     try {
        this.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     System.out.println("Thread 3 has terminated");
  }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {     
    Thread tr1 = new Thread1();
    Thread tr2 = new Thread2();
    Thread tr3 = new Thread3();
    tr1.start();
    tr2.start();
    tr3.start();        
}
```

current output:

```
Thread 1 running...
Thread 3 running...
Thread 2 running...
Thread 3 has terminated
Thread 2 has terminated
Thread 1 has terminated
```

desired output:

```
Thread 1 running...
Thread 2 running...
Thread 3 running...
Thread 3 has terminated
Thread 2 has terminated
Thread 1 has terminated
```

Comment: _...threads...in a particular order...using only sleep()._  Thread.sleep() is OK for demos, but don't rely on it to synchronize threads in an important program.  Any `sleep(n)` call can last longer, than `n` milliseconds, especially on a loaded system.  Even if it does not last _much_ longer, a program that repeatedly sleep()s will build up cumulative error.  If you want to _guarantee_ things happening in a particular order, then you should use guaranteed synchonization objects (Semaphores, queues, countdown latches, etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your threads are started in right order, but output can be wrong because output messages arrive concurrently. You should move messaging into the main thread:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {     
    Thread tr1 = new Thread1();
    Thread tr2 = new Thread2();
    Thread tr3 = new Thread3();
    tr1.start();
    System.out.println("Thread 1 started");
    tr2.start();
    System.out.println("Thread 2 started");
    tr3.start();      
    System.out.println("Thread 3 started");  
}
```

Comment: They are started in the right order, but it is not guaranteed that they will **run** in the same order...

Comment: @jamp yes, absolutely. This is also a factor which can lead to such random output.

Comment: This matter with threads is very mysterious to me, glad you helped me guys.

Answer (score 0):

You can make Util class, witch must be thread safe, and make synchronized method to print.

```
public class Utils {
      public static synchronized void printStuff(String msg) {
             System.out.println(msg);
      }
}
```

Now in Thread1, Thread2 and Thread3 use this Utils.printStuff("Text") to print in console.

Comment: this won't help to get desired output, because it is unpredictable which particular thread among several concurrent threads will obtain this implicit lock first. Locking by `synchronized` is always unfair. BTW, `System.out.println()` is already synchronized.

Comment: Output:
Thread 1 running...
Thread 2 running...
Thread 3 running...
Thread 3 has terminated
Thread 2 has terminated
Thread 1 has terminated
But you are right, there is no warranty for desired output.